# Android Studio Bottom Toolbar has disappeared

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio's bottom Toolbar has disappeared. I tried to see where someone got the answer but couldn't find it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Bottom Toolbar Invisible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press `Alt+1`, `Alt+2`, `Alt+3`, `Alt+4`, `Alt+5`, `Alt+6`, `Alt+7`, `Alt+8`

Answer (score 3):

Go to `View > Appearance` and enable `Toolbar` and `Tool Window Bars`.

[image: android studio top bar]

Comment: `Tool Window Bars` helped.

Answer (score 2):

Select View -> Appearance -> check Tool Window Bars and Status Bar

Comment: It is all checked

Comment: Still can't see